# Is there a URL that will take the respondent directly to survey questions (no "respond to survey" button to click)

Tags: survey-list

I was able to generate a URL in Sharepoint 2007 that took survey invitees directly to the survey questions (not the opportunity to click on a "respond to the survey" button).  I cannot figure out how to do this in Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 7):

It's something like `http://sp2010/Lists/TestSurvey/NewForm.aspx`

To find it go to your survey click "respond to the survey", when the dialog opens rightclick and select properties, copy the address except `?IsDlg=1`

Comment: Make sure you click in the white box rather than the top part of the browser window.

Comment: You can use jQuery to replace the "Respond to Survey" button with a direct link.  Just find the id of the button using Firebug and replace the `innerHTML`.