# How do I get the URL for a list so that I can send it to an individual without them seeing the standard view with the 'add new item' icon?

Tags: list

I am using Sharepoint 2010. In Sharepoint 2007 I was able to click the 'add new item' icon which brought up the list in a questionnaire format - i could then use this link to send out and individuals could complete the list. In Sharepoint 2010, I can't seem to do the same thing. When I click on 'add new item' the URL for the 'questionnaire' view is the same as the URL for the standard view and I do not want individuals to see this part of the list.

Comment: are you using Surveys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure is same as SP2007, it's not directly shown though, you can find it like this -

```
http://yousite/Lists/listname/NewForm.aspx
```

You can send out this link, but after completing the question when user press finish page will be redirected to AllItems.aspx, you have to think a way of avoiding that, either hide the view in that page and using the link like http:// yoursite/Lists/listname/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder='view/link of the same site where you want to redirect user'

Answer (score 0):

Cindy,

This question has been asked previously on this forum, [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34870/is-there-a-url-that-will-take-the-respondent-directly-to-survey-questions-no-r)

I guess this is what you want right ?

> It's something like `http://sp2010/Lists/TestSurvey/NewForm.aspx`
>
> To find it go to your survey click "respond to the survey", when the
>   dialog opens rightclick and select properties, copy the address except
>   ?IsDlg=1

Redirect to another page on completion: In both 2007 and 2010 you can add “?Source=” and specify a page to go to after the survey has been completed. The destination (Source) could be the survey home page, the site’s home page or a custom “Thank you” page.

[Here are the complete details](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-modifying-respond-to-this.html)

Comment: Hi, Yes this is what I am looking for. But when I open my list, click add new item and right click, as instructed is: http://vtbenet/hrmentoring/Lists/Mentor%20Questionnaire/AllItems.aspx which doesnt include ?IsDlg=1

Comment: Is there a work around at all? appreciate your help

Comment: p.s I am using a list not a survey  unsure if this is the reason why I am not getting the  ?IsDlg=1

Comment: http://vtbenet/hrmentoring/Lists/Mentor%20Questionnaire/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EList&VisibilityContext=http://vtbenet/hrmentoring/SitePages/Mentor%20Questionnaire%20Submission%20Confirmation.aspx?PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage

Comment: Cindy, I cannot view your SharePoint environment until its on Public Facing license... is it? Also, why are you not using Surveys if its just Question with multiple choices to select from?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Do you know if there is a reason why I am not getting the ?IsDlg=1 at the end of my URL when I click on properties? it's just http://mysite/Lists/Listnames/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Although adding the ?source= and a link to a confirmation page may stop the individual from looking at the standard view. I want to be able to stop them from seeing it from the offset oreven having to click the 'Add new item' icon.

Comment: Hi, just to let you know I have fixed the problem. I unchecked the dialogs field which meant the URL of a new item was different to the list and then I was able to do as you advised, thank you for your help

Comment: Cindy, great you find your answer and I was of some help - Please mark the answer as correct/accept as answer to close the question!